# Nginx. Назначить произвольному префиксному location ПРОИЗВОЛЬНЫЙ маршрут в файловой системе

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm, php-nginx

Я использую nginx и хочу разделить фронтэнд и бэкэнд части сайта. Грубо говоря, хочу, чтоб файлы фронта загружались из одной папки, а файлы бэка из другой.

1. Есть жесткая привязка к домену и поддомены использовать нельзя.
2. Есть так же строгое ограничение, что файлы фронта и бэка не могут
   храниться в одной папке.

Поэтому, к файлам фронта я хочу обращаться
    таким образом: `my-domain.org/some-file`,
    а к файлам бэка таким:
    `my-domain.org/admin/some-file`.
    Вот пробую это сделать при помощи
    такой конфигурации:

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.loc www.domain.loc;
    index index.php index.html;

    error_log   /var/log/nginx/domain.loc-error.log;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domain.loc-access.log;

    location /
    {
        root /home/www/domain.loc/frontend/web;
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php;
        }
        try_files   $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Перенаправление php-файлов к серверу «PHP-FPM»
        location ~ "^(/.+?\.php)(/.*)?$"
        {
            # Проверяем существование файлов, пробуем исправить если нет, иначе выдаём ошибку
            # $1 указывает на первую скобку в регулярном выражении выше - собственно адрес запрошенного php файла
            try_files $1 $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php =404;
            include common/php-fpm;
        }
    }

    location /admin
    {
        root /home/www/domain.loc/backend/web;

        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /admin/index.php;
        }

        location ~ ^/admin(.*)?$
        {
            try_files  $1 $1/ =404;
            location ~ \.php$
            {
                try_files /index.php =404;
                include common/php-fpm;
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Помогите разобраться, что не так? По-сути, нужно назначить произвольному префиксному location произвольный маршрут в файловой системе. Nginx же предполагает, что префикс всегда является частью маршрута в файловой системе. Для красоты и стройности, хотелось бы обойти это ограничение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял в Вашем вопросе, то смотрим [модуль ngx_http_core_module](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html):

[location](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location):

> Устанавливает конфигурацию в зависимости от URI запроса...

[root](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root):

> Задаёт корневой каталог для запросов... Путь к файлу формируется путём простого добавления URI к значению директивы root. Если же URI необходимо поменять, следует воспользоваться директивой alias.

[alias:](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)

> Задаёт замену для указанного location’а... Если location и последняя часть значения директивы совпадают, то лучше воспользоваться директивой root.

В Вашем случае:

```
location /       { root  /home/www/domain.loc/frontend/web; }
location /admin/ { alias /home/www/domain.loc/backend/web/; }
```